# How to partition the contents in a buffer in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, partitioning

I have to create a wordcount program in C using Posix. I also have to use multithreading using pthreads by reading the input file into a buffer and then paritioning that buffer given how many threads are going to be used. Then, each thread should count the number of words in its partition. The problem is i cant find any sources at all for splitting or partitioning the contents in a buffer. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Just do it manually. In general, if your buffer has 80 characters and you have four threads, have thread 1 look at characters 0 - 19, thread 2 look at characters 20 - 39, and so on. In your case, since you're splitting words, you'll have to look around those boundaries to make sure you don't break in the middle of a word.

Comment: If you've got POSIX, you could use `mmap()` to map the file into memory, and then simply give each thread a section of the mapped memory to process.  For example, four threads, give each 1/4 of the memory to work on.  You'll need to think about start and end-points; what happens if a word straddles the boundary between two threads?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming your program stores the file as a pointer to an array of characters, you might achieve a similar result by representing a "partition" of the buffer as a pointer to the start of your partition and an integer to represent the size of the partition.

The code snippet below may help you with partitioning the buffer.

```
struct buffer_partition {
  char* start;
  int size;
}

void* word_count(void* arg) {
  struct buffer_partition* buffer=(struct buffer_partition*)arg;
  /* do word counting with buffer->start
     be careful to not access characters after buffer->size */    
}

int main() {
  /* read input */
  struct buffer_partition* partition = (struct buffer_partition*)malloc(sizeof(struct buffer_partition));
  partition->start=buffer+offset;
  partition->size=size_of_each_partition;
  pthread_create(thread_pointer, extra_attributes, word_count, partition);
  /* sum all results, print answer :) */
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this really gave me a good starting point.